# Razor Dynamic Models Breaking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, razor

I created a C# Razor site with no explicit model definitions, relying on the `dynamic` keyword to represent my model.  However, this is now breaking because it says that "object doesn't contain member X".  It does contain it; intellisense shows this, but whatever is using the model, when dynamic, is breaking.  Even adding `@model dynamic` doesn't work.

Changing to an explicit model is working, so I'm doing that, but what would cause dynamic support to stop working in process?

**EDIT:**

My controller simply does this:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
  return View(new
  {
     Data = repos.GetData() 
  });
}
```

and the uses it directly:

```
@{ Title = "X" }

@foreach (var item in Model.Data)
{
   Render
}
```

The model and data is not null, and there is valid data.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your Action method and View code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to utilize dynamic types to be passed, you should use the `ViewBag` property.  Your code could read:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
  ViewBag.Data = repos.GetData();

  return View();
}
```

Your View:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Data)
{
   Render
}
```

I tried to get your code working but I also throw the same error.

Comment: Well that's weird because it was working this whole time for weeks until today, with no problems.

Comment: @BrianMains Well is there something else that changed in your code today?  *Something* must have changed.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Model:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
   dynamic returnModel = new ExpandoObject();
   returnModel.Data = repos.GetData();
   return View(returnModel);
}
```

View:

```
@{ 
  ViewBag.Title = "title";
}

@foreach (var item in Model.Data)
{
   // html for item
}
```